# android facebook sdk .setCaption does not show caption on Sharedialog?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am sharing a photo using facebook sdk but caption does not show up .. is there any way to show caption ?

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(photobitmap)
                .setCaption("Photo made by")
                .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();
        ShareApi.share(content, null);
        shareDialog.show(content);
```